# ¿Cómo asignar el nombre de una tabla a una variable? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

Necesito asignar el nombre de una tabla a una variable para luego utilizarlo más adelante en el query que voy a ejecutar, y no estar cambiando el nombre en cada punto donde llamo a la tabla.

```
DECLARE @variable TABLE = nombre_tabla
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM @variable
```

Esta variable quiero asignarla luego para un código como este, en el que al final (en la fila del WHERE) lo pongo como una condición (asignándolo a 'sysobjects.name'):

```
SELECT nombre_tabla=sysobjects.name, fecha_creacion=sysobjects.crdate, nombre_columna=syscolumns.name, tipo=systypes.name, capacidad=syscolumns.length
FROM sysobjects JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
                JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U' AND sysobjects.name = @variable
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid
```

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Lo que pides no se puede y tendrías que crear código dinámico. Sin embargo, eso llega a indicar un posible problema de diseño de la base de datos o del sistema en si.

Answer (score 1):

No tienes que declarar la variable, sino poner el alias en la propia select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MiTabla m 
WHERE m.Campo1 = 'Hola' AND m.Campo2 = 'Adios'
```

En este ejemplo, decimos que a la tabla `MiTabla` le asignamos el alias `m` de ahí en adelante nos referimos a `MiTabla` como `m`.

Pero eso solo se hace dentro de la misma consulta, no es una variable para usar en todo un procedimiento almacenado, por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias Carlos. Pero, ¿Cómo podría hacer si yo quiero asignar ese nombre de tabla como un string a un condicional? Como se puede ver en el siguiente ejemplo, en la fila del WHERE:

SELECT nombre_tabla=sysobjects.name, fecha_creacion=sysobjects.crdate, nombre_columna=syscolumns.name, tipo=systypes.name, capacidad=syscolumns.length
FROM sysobjects JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
                JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U' AND sysobjects.name = **@tabla**
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid

Comment: @joandiar91 lo que está haciendo en ese ejemplo es comparar el campo `name` de la tabla `sysobjects` con la variable `@tabla`  que tiene que ser un varchar o algo similar, es decir, un string. En ese caso declararías la variable como `DECLARE @tabla varchar(150) = 'nombre_de_la_tabla'` (por ejemplo) y luego la puedes usar en comparaciones como en el ejemplo que has puesto.

Answer (score 1):

No se si esto sea lo que buscas pero así seria una forma para mandarle cualquier nombre de tabla por variable.

```
 DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(200)
    SET @Variable = 'Nombre_tabla'
    
SELECT nombre_tabla=sysobjects.name, fecha_creacion=sysobjects.crdate, nombre_columna=syscolumns.name, tipo=systypes.name, capacidad=syscolumns.length
FROM sysobjects JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
                JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U' AND sysobjects.name = @Variable
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice para poder usar la variable con el nombre de la tabla en una de las condiciones del WHERE y luego en un SELECT, fue utilizar la función EXECUTE para el SELECT:

```
DECLARE @tabla VARCHAR(40)
SET @tabla = 'Nombre_tabla'

SELECT nombre_tabla=sysobjects.name, fecha_creacion=sysobjects.crdate, nombre_columna=syscolumns.name, tipo=systypes.name, capacidad=syscolumns.length
FROM sysobjects JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
                JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U' AND sysobjects.name = @tabla
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid

EXECUTE ('SELECT TOP 3 * FROM '+@tabla)
```

Answer (score 1):

En Tsql no se puede hacer directamente una asignación de un nombre de un objeto, para consultarlo.

Se puede hacer utilizando una query dinámica. Tienes que declarar una variable de tipo `nvarchar(128)` o `sysname` y asignarle el valor del nombre de la tabla. Luego a una sentencia que asignas a otra variable de tipo `nvarchar`, como puedes observar en el ejemplo, le agregas la sentencia, y le concatenas el nombre de la variable.

Por último llamas a la ejecución dinámica de la misma. Esto se puede hacer con `exec` o con `exec sp_executeSql`. Te recomiendo la segunda manera, ya que el procedure sp_ExecuteSql te pueden ayudar a evitar el problema de las **querys dinámicas**.

```
DECLARE @variable nvarchar(128) = N'NombreTabla'

DECLARE @Sentencia nvarchar(4000);
SET @Sentencia = N'SELECT TOP 3 * FROM ' + @variable + ';';

Exec sp_executeSql @sentencia ;
```

Ahora bien, esto es susceptible de tener `SQL INJECTION`.

El procedure sp_ExecuteSql, puede permitir utilizar parámetros para evitar esto, pero tiene su dificultad, en función de lo que quieras hacer.

[Sql dinámico, ¿Cómo se hace?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/03/sql-dinamico-como-se-hace/)